# How to wirelessly send commands from a wireless device to raspberry pi and read them?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a project using raspberry pi in which I need to perform certain tasks based on wireless commands like a button press. Lets assume that i want to switch on an LED connected to a raspberry pi wirelessly by a button press from a button connected elsewhere. How can i control the python program running in my raspberry pi wirelessly?

Comment: By wireless do you mean radio frequences/bluetooth/wifi direct/local network over the internet?

Comment: anything which does not need the internet. let's just assume i want to control stuff in the pi from a remote. i sort of have no idea about it, so i might not explain myself properly. but i hope you get my question now.

Comment: Its still a little vague, I would suggest to look into wireless technologies that suit your needs. For example, if you do not want to use a network (local or internet connected) then you may want to look into using bluetooth, infra-red or wireless radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TCP client-server socket. This works with wired and wireless communication.

What model RPi are you using for this project? If it is a RPi 3 model B, and if you prefer wireless mode, you can utilize the onboard bluetooth or WiFi for this purpose.

TCP Client-Server Socket [tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) . Please go through this page . its in C code though. 
Hope this helps.

Sam.

Answer (score 4):

From my point of view, as mentioned aboved, the TCP client-server socket is not really good idea. Socket is good for real-time data streaming. However its a real pain to create connection to it. Once you disrupt connection(incorrect disconnection), which is very easy to do, you will block your port and you will end up with infamous 'Address already in use' error.

If you want simple, powerful and very scalable solution, I strongly advise you **2 options**.

**1) MQTT**

MQTT is beatiful solution from IBM, its subscribe/publishing message protocol (works on TCP or websockets). You simply install MQTT broker(server) on your raspberry pi(very easy). Broker is running always so you dont have to care about it at all

in second step, you create program on your raspberry pi that will subscribe to the broker under some specific topic. Beauty about it is that you can subscribe to the broker from anywhere. This program(subscriber) will be receiving any messages on particular topic and based on published messages you can program your logic

third step is to create publisher. You simply give address, port of your broker and and publish messages under particular topic. Publisher can be your phone, PC, digitalocean server... whatever.

There are already working examples if you search python implementation of MQTT -> paho-mqtt

[The idea in image](https://res.cloudinary.com/goeventz/image/fetch/c_scale/f_auto,q_auto/https%3A%2F%2Fd24oe5tmwdgz7x.cloudfront.net%2Fevent%2F65847%2Fbanner%2Fevent_1521444906.jpg)

**2) Flask server**

I like using Flask because it is scalable, undestructable and you will not meet any problems with implementation.

You simply setup flask server on raspberry pi(super easy) and create API that will control whatever you want on your raspberry. 
For example by calling 10.0.0.10:5000/LED?state=on will turn on LED and etc.

***As I already said, I strongly discourage you from using socket-server&client. Socket is great, but its for very specific things and you need a lot of effort to make it scalable and error-resistant.***